# Using gawk to combine data points with same number before decimals

Tags: unix, awk, command-line, numbers, gawk

I have a file that has things listed like this but I want to compress it so that there are no longer decimals after the numbers, and so that the range that is given spans from the smallest decimal to the largest decimal.

The numbers that I want to remove the decimals from are in the fourth column.
The ranges are in the 2nd and 3rd column such that h23.1 spans from 9380 to 10000.

Input

```
7   9380        10000       h23.1   word
7   10000       10240       h23.2   words
7   10240       10750       h23.3   words
8    7050        7270        t23.11  word
8    7270        7310        t23.12  word
8    7310        7930        t23.13  words
8    7930        8020        t23.2   word
8    8020        8340        t23.31  word
8    8340        8610        t23.32  words
8    8610        8970        t23.33  word
12   6600        6980        t15     word
12   5630        6140        h14.1   words
12   6140        6340        h14.2   word
12   6340        6600        h14.3   words
```

Expected output

```
7 9380 10750 h23
8 7050 8970 t23
12 6600 6980 t15
12 5630 6600 h14
```

Comment: Pieter21 was really hinting "What have you tried?". See [ask].

Comment: http://www.catonmat.net/category/awk-programming has some stuff that's well worth a read. awk one-liners and tips and tricks. Will be a little less daunting than reading the awk manual. But really *learn awk*. You won't regret it.  You will still be using it 40 years from now.

Comment: @NiallCosgrove I know a bit of awk but I didn't think it was able to compare stuff in different rows (the line starting with 7 is a combination of row 1-3), whenver I've used it it's been something like "if the the 3rd column matches what you are looking for, print the first column" but this is only in one row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ sub(/\..*/,"",$4) }
$4 != prev[4] {
    if (NR>1) {
        print start, prev[3], prev[4]
    }
    start = $1 OFS $2
}
{ split($0,prev) }
END { print start, prev[3], prev[4] }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
7 9380 10750 h23
8 7050 8970 t23
12 6600 6980 t15
12 5630 6600 h14
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution, but some hints:

- for each line, convert the 4th column to a "key"
- store the first column in an associative array to map it to the key

  - I assume that the value in the first column will be constant for each key
- keep other arrays to store the minimum and maximum values of columns 2 and 3 respectively

  - hint: the first time you see this key, you'll have to store columns 2 and 3 as the min and max values
- after you have read the whole file (i.e. in the `END` block) iterate over the arrays, printing the values.

Another approach that is a bit simpler is to do something when the key *changes*. Your input data is sorted-ish, so you can keep track of the *previous* key, and when it differs from the *current* key, you can print out the min and max values you have kept track of, and then reset the min and max to the values from the current line.